# Using amazon cloudfront to stream on demand without using s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp, ondemand

Can i use cloudfront for dristibute the content(mp3) via rtmp on demand using a non-amazon service(S3) but, instead using an other sever that has the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. See the second sentence in the manual: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/StreamingDistributionS3Origin.html